# How does a DBMS solve the following query?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, rdbms

Suppose I have a table Table1 with attributes id, Name, Address, Salary. Now, I write the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE 2*Salary > (SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Table1)
```

It is obvious that the query

```
SELECT MAX(Salary) FROM Table1
```

will produce the same result for each and every row in Table1. So does the DBMS execute this aggregation query once for each row or does it executes it once and stores the value to be compared with each row? If so, how does the DBMS decide that the result of this query is independent of rows in Table1?

Because, I was wondering that executing it once for each row will be highly inefficient.

Comment: Your sub-query is not correlated. So it will be calculated once.

Comment: it decides that the results are independent, because it doesn't refer to any tables from the outer query.

Answer (score 1):

Try this to first store the max value in variable and Then use that variable

```
Declare @Salary money
    SELECT @Salary=MAX(Salary) FROM #yourTable
    SELECT * FROM #yourTable WHERE 2*Salary > @Salary
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `CROSS JOIN` or `,` like this:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM 
    Table1 t1
    CROSS JOIN
    (SELECT MAX(Salary) As maxSalary
     FROM Table1) t2
WHERE t1.Salary * 2 > t2.maxSalary
```

> **Note :**
>   Most of RDBM systems at first cash tables then seek over them. So I am actually adding a `maxSalary` field to your `Table1`.

I think the query works, because I can 't test it right now.